# Determining assembly name for use with PHP DOTNET

Tags: php, .net, speech-recognition

I am trying to  use Microsoft's Speech Platform 11 through PHP's DOTNET object
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj127858.aspx

The platform should be instantiated as follows

```
$platform = new DOTNET("assembly-name", "Microsoft.Speech.Recognition");
```

But how to retrieve the assembly name for Speech Platform 11? (to replace "assembly-name" in the initialization call)

I have tried several assembly names by... guesswork, obviously with no luck.
The initialization error being thrown

```
Failed to instantiate .Net object [CreateInstance] [0x80070002] The system cannot find the file specified
```

**UPDATE**

With the following code, I was able to get PHP to find and use the assembly

```
$full_assembly_string = 'Microsoft.Speech, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35';
$full_class_name = 'Microsoft.Speech.Recognition.SpeechRecognitionEngine';

$interface = new DOTNET($full_assembly_string, $full_class_name);
```

However, there's a new roadblock:

```
Failed to instantiate .Net object [Unwrapped, QI for IDispatch] [0x80004002] No such interface supported
```

At first glance it seems it has to do with COM visibility. But if for any reason the class isn't visible to COM (and it seems odd), how to change this? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Not tested. Just another guess.

According to the Microsoft Speech Platform SDK 11 Docs:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.aspx

i would give this a try:

- "assembly" `Microsoft.Speech`
- "classname" `Microsoft.Speech.Recognition.SpeechRecognitionEngine`
- `Microsoft.Speech.Recognition` is only the namespace

  ```
  $sre = new DOTNET(
      'Microsoft.Speech',
      'Microsoft.Speech.Recognition.SpeechRecognitionEngine'
  );
  ```

Methods are documented here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine_members(v=office.14).aspx#Anchor_2

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately it fails the same way. The "System cannot find the file specified" error, however, makes me think the problem could be somewhere else. By firing up Process Monitor, I noticed that PHP is doing something odd: it searches for the Speech Platform files WITHIN its own directory.   c:\Program Files (x86)\Php7\Microsoft.Speech\Microsoft.Speech.dll   and, obviously, fails

Comment: I suggest to add the path with the dll to the PATH var. I assume the normal DLL lookup order applies. (There are so many caveats that do not appear in the manuals. Its a mess.)

Comment: Baby steps: the DLL is now found (see updated question) but the initiation fails with "Failed to instantiate .Net object [Unwrapped, QI for IDispatch] [0x80004002] No such interface supported". There may be another of those caveats that are not mentioned anywhere: visibility of the interface to COM. Any hint about this issue?